# Create-react-app with node-sass doesn't catch/persist @debug/@warn rule in terminal

Tags: reactjs, sass, node-sass

I have used create-react-app and installed node-sass as a depandency. The react version is V16.13.1., and the node-sass version is V4.14.1. Both should be the latest version as then.

My question is if I use @debug $some-variable in my scss file, it doesn't show up in my terminal. However, what is interesting is when I kill the terminal and restart it again, it pops up for a fraction of second and disappear again. The same happens to @warn rule as well.

The workaround is to use @error instead, @error rule always intercepts the terminal and 100% pops up errors, I used it as a work around to debug my scss code.

But I believe the problem is on node-sass side, @debug/@warn should print out something, but just got overwritten on react scripts side, i.e. by *"react-scripts start"* script. In my opinion, there should be a way to block react side to do that, and persist the stdout info on the terminal. Maybe add a flag into node-sass or modify the **start** script on react side?

I hope I got the problem addressed properly. Does anyone has experience on this issue? Please advise.

Example code:

In foo.scss file:

```
   @debug "hello world"  // it does not print anything in terminal
   @warn "this is a warning" // it does not print anything in terminal either
   @error "it definately catch this"  // the error shows up in terminal only
```